# How to extract tar.gz file without terminal

Tags: tar

Could anyone tell me an easy way to extract tar.gz file without using the terminal or any exclusive archive manager? thanks.

Comment: If you don't use the terminal or the built in archive manager which handles the GUI equivalent commands you are kinda out of luck.  The archive manager is a built in in the Desktop, so that should work, but if you don't want to use that you have no solution.

Comment: I am sorry, this was a dumb question. I will try to take it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract a tar.gz file without the terminal, just simply,1) open the file manager, 2) navigate to the tar.gz file , 3) double click on the file , 4) either copy the contents out of the tar.gz into another folder or just click extract and select the destination from there! And that's it.. You're Done!

Comment: This, of course, *is* using an archive manager. OP's question as currently stated is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just right-click on the tar.gz file and select the `extract here` option from the drop-down menu. It will be extracted on the same folder as the compressed file.

Comment: @Alban You are right, of course. The way the question was written I'd read it as meaning an _add-on_ archive manager (like PeaZip, DAR, tar, FreeArc or Ark), rather than the one built into Gnome.  Although, I guess that my reading of the OP's question must have been correct in this case since, as you say, my answer is basically the same as the already accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY don't want to use an archive manager or command line, you could use a python script like the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30888321/5090081)  although admittedly it seems odd that you wouldn't want to use an archive manager but python would be okay.